# Azure build stopped working when using xproj based ASP.NET Core project

Tags: git, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have a webapp on Azure that is setup with continuous integration via BitBucket repo.

My last build and commit (which was successful) was on 5/25. I did a commit today to a couple *.cs files, as well as 2 *.cshtml files.

Now, my Azure build is failing on step 2 (step 1 is 'Updating submodules').

> Preparing deployment for commit id 'xxxxxxxx'

And here's the beautiful error that is in the log, this is the ENTIRE log:

> 'D:\home\site\repository*.xproj' is not a deployable project.

What in the world?!?! What am I supposed to do with that?

Here's a summary of **my** changes that were in **my** release:

- changing value of a string constant
- adding additional `parms.Add("parameter", parameterValue);`
- add parameters to method signatures
- adding/changing/removing `div`s in cshtml files

all normal stuff; NOTHING changed on the xproj file. Why would the build start failing now? Have there been any issues with building on Azure since 5/25?

I hope this is the correct forum for Azure build stuff, since there's not really any code that I can place here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because support for the old xproj format has been removed. Please see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ae43643f-d4d6-4a5d-8c7c-4877eb72fcf0/deprecation-of-old-projectjson-format-in-aspnet-core-apps?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/1) for announcements.

You need to migrate to the csproj format. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migration/ for detailed steps.

Comment: Thanks, went through this last night. Had some hiccups, but finally got it to work. One of the workarounds from the upgrade I found was to comment out the "tools", and "scripts" sections of project.json. Now after successfully converting, my site.min.css is never getting updated...that's my next task.

Comment: Great! Might also be worth commenting on that article if you find conversion tips that you think might help others.

Comment: The one tip that was not stated/obvious, was to download and install the .NET Core SDK. If that would have been done first, maybe my tools and scripts part would not have been necessary. I guess I'll find out when I upgrade my Surface in the next few days...